# Python3: Use a variable defined within a function

Tags: function, variables, python-3.x

I am confused over this behavior seen in Python3 and I was wondering if there is a way around it or if I am doing something wrong.

I have seen this in the command-line and scripts. I define a function called "SETVAR()". SETVAR() will use getpass.getuser() (which was imported) and save the output to the variable USER. The function is executed, but when USER is printed, I get an error stating the variable was not defined. If I define the variable outside of a function, all is well. However, in my scripts, I want to use variables defined and made in a function. Can it be done?

```
>>> def SETVAR():
...     USER = getpass.getuser()
... 
>>> SETVAR()
>>> print(USER)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'USER' is not defined

>>> USER = getpass.getuser()
>>> print(USER)
collier
```

Question: How do I use variables defined and created in functions that have been defined and executed whether in the command-line or script?

Comment: No up-votes? I thought this was a good question. It definitely has a great answer.

Comment: Why did this get down-voted? What could I have done differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you define and create the variable inside a function, you can let Python know that you want the resulting variable to be globally accessible;

```
>> def SETVAR():
...     global USER
...     USER='olle'
... 
>>> SETVAR()
>>> print(USER)
olle
>>>
```

EDIT: I tend to agree with @Wooble in the comments that this is something you may want to think twice about using in most circumstances. For simple scripts it can be very useful, but for more complex situations it can make the code hard to follow.

Comment: Thanks! I will be able to accept this answer in nine minutes (so says the server).

Comment: You should include a disclaimer about how this is almost always a bad idea and don't do it.